# How to connect to EC2 instance using access key id and secret access key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to remote into my EC2 instance's public IP address. Almost all of the documentation I have read to do this requires using either a .pem or .ppk file. Is there any way to connect to an instance using an access key id and secret access key?

Comment: You can connect using the [Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-sessions-start.html#sessions-start-cli)

Comment: @AnonCoward thanks for providing those docs. I looked through it and it still suggests I need a .pem key for access. Is this the case or is it possible to use just an access key id + secret access key to connect to the EC2?

Comment: You connect with `aws ssm start-session`, which does not involve a .pem key (well, it does, but the AWS CLI handles creating an ephemeral key for you behind the scenes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 ways to login to an Amazon EC2 Linux instance:

#### SSH

When the Amazon EC2 instance is launched, select a keypair that is already loaded into AWS. When the instance launches, the public half of the keypair will be copied into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for the `ec2-user`.

You can then login to the instance using the private keypair:

```
ssh -i keypair.pem ec2-user@1.1.1.1
```

#### EC2 Instance Connect

EC2 Instance Connect has two features:

- The ability to push a 'temporary keypair' to the EC2 instance
- The ability to establish an SSH connection via a web browser

Permission can be granted to an IAM User to use EC2 Instance Connect. Therefore, a user can login to the EC2 instance by using their AWS credentials. They are effectively requesting a connect via EC2 Instance Connect, and all the SSH stuff is done in the background.

#### AWS Systems Manager Session Manager

Amazon EC2 instances launched with Amazon Linux have an SSM Agent installed. This agent 'calls back' to AWS and offers the ability to use **Session Manager** to login to the instance. This isn't an SSH connection -- rather, it is a connection to the Agent, which runs commands in an interactive session.

Session Manager offers the ability to connect to **instances in private subnets** because the Agent is creating an *outbound* connection to AWS. (The other two methods above cannot be used to connect to an instance in a private subnet).

The ability to use Session Manager is based on permissions of the IAM User.