# AWS cli: How to stop instances and start EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want to start and stop `EC2` instances using `AWS-cli`

How can i do this task.

I have setup aws cli on my pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Start an Amazon EC2 instance**

Documentation: [start-instances — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/start-instances.html)

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-xxx
```

**Stop an Amazon EC2 instance**

Documentation: [stop-instances — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/stop-instances.html)

```
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-xxx
```

Comment: hi how to start an instance and login. example using ubuntu

Comment: @Santhosh See: [How to connect to EC2 instance using access key id and secret access key?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73243519/174777)